# Node TLS client connection automatically sends a 'close notify' message (but only in Docker)

Tags: node.js, docker, ssl, tls1.2

I am coding a Node application which requires me to create a TLS client to connect to a remote host.  I'm running into an issue where my TLS connection will work properly when the application is run outside of Docker, however when run inside it will send a 'close notify' message immediately before the first message from the TLS server is received.

My TS for a TLS client is as follows:

```
const socket = tls.connect(
      {
        host: host,
        port: port,
        cert: certificate
        key: key
      },
      () => {
        logger.info('client connected', socket.authorized ? 'authorized' : 'unauthorized');

// Business logic to notify the user we're connected

        process.stdin.pipe(socket);
        process.stdin.resume();
      }
    );

    socket.on('data', (data: Buffer) => {
// Processing the data received from the server here
    });

    socket.on('error', () => {
// Business logic to notify the user the connection had an error.  This is not called when the
// connection is closed
    });

    socket.on('close', hadError => {
// Business logic to notify the user the connection has been closed.  hadError is false
// when this callback is called.
    });
```

I added extra logging using the socket.enableTrace() function built into the socket class and other than things like gmt_unix_time, random_bytes, and session_id all values are identical between a bare metal and Docker application.  Here are the logs I saw:

```
TLS 1: client _init handle? true
**I'm only using self-signed certs in the dev environment**
(node:1) Warning: Setting the NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED environment variable to '0' makes TLS connections and HTTPS requests insecure by disabling certificate verification.
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
TLS 1: client initRead handle? true buffered? false
TLS 1: client _start handle? true connecting? false requestOCSP? false

Client sends handshake
Client receives handshake
Client receives ChangeCipherSpec
Client receives ApplicationData (continuing handshake)

Sent Record
Header:
  Version = TLS 1.2 (0x303)
  Content Type = ApplicationData (23)
  Length = 281
  Inner Content Type = Handshake (22)
    CertificateVerify, Length=260
      Signature Algorithm: rsa_pss_rsae_sha256 (0x0804)
      Signature (len=256): <snip>

Sent Record
Header:
  Version = TLS 1.2 (0x303)
  Content Type = ApplicationData (23)
  Length = 69
  Inner Content Type = Handshake (22)
    Finished, Length=48
      verify_data (len=48): <snip>



TLS 1: client onhandshakedone
TLS 1: client _finishInit handle? true alpn false servername false
**Sees the self-signed cert, but I'm ignoring this in my dev environment**
TLS 1: client emit secureConnect. rejectUnauthorized: false, authorizationError: SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN
Sent Record
Header:
  Version = TLS 1.2 (0x303)
  Content Type = ApplicationData (23)
  Length = 521
  Inner Content Type = ApplicationData (23)

** Here is where the client is sending the close notify**

Sent Record
Header:
  Version = TLS 1.2 (0x303)
  Content Type = ApplicationData (23)
  Length = 19
  Inner Content Type = Alert (21)
    Level=warning(1), description=close notify(0)

Received Record
Header:
  Version = TLS 1.2 (0x303)
  Content Type = ApplicationData (23)
  Length = 453
  Inner Content Type = ApplicationData (23)

** Here is where the server is acking the close notify**

Received Record
Header:
  Version = TLS 1.2 (0x303)
  Content Type = ApplicationData (23)
  Length = 19
  Inner Content Type = Alert (21)
    Level=warning(1), description=close notify(0)
```

My docker compose file is exposing and publishing the TLS port in use for this connection.

My development server runs Ubuntu 22.04 whereas official Node Docker images run a Debian environment, so I developed my own Dockerfile from scratch however that did not change the behavior.  Another thing I noticed was that the version of openssl was different between bare-metal and Docker (v3 vs v1), however making a custom Dockerfile which uses openssl v3 did not change anything either.

I can establish a generic TCP connection using a similar pattern in my code in both a bare metal and Docker environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I have been able to find out, the reason the close_notify is sent is because my TLS client requires access to stdin.  When I was running the app in Docker I wasn't using the --interactive flag so it didn't have access to stdin.  Setting this flag allowed the connection to persist.